# Give user error message when input data is incorrect in python

Tags: python-3.x

Only 5 `currencies` are to be used in a python currency `converter tool––(USD, EUR, CAD, GBP, and CHF)`. If user inputs a different currency in `convertFrom or convertTo`, how do I add an error message informing user to `try again`?

## Conversion

```
convertFrom = input("What currency would you like to convert from? ")

amount = int(input("How much of that currency would you like to convert? "))

convertTo = input("Which currency would you like to convert to? ")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a list of valid currencies

```
validCurrencies = ["EUR","GBP","USD","CAD", "CHF"]
```

Then you can validate the input by

```
currencyFrom = ""

while not currencyFrom in validCurrencies:
  currencyFrom = input("What currency would you like to convert from: (e.g. GBP)").upper()
  if not currencyFrom in validCurrencies:
    print("Invalid Currency, Please Try again")
print("correct Currency please follow next instructions")
```

output:

```
What currency would you like to convert from: (e.g. GBP) uuu
Invalid Currency, Please Try again
What currency would you like to convert from: (e.g. GBP) Gbp
correct Currency please follow next instructions
```

You can do the same for convertTo and amount

Answer (score 1):

Create a list of currencies that your program supports.

When the user enters a currency, before converting it, check if that currency exists in your list. If it does not, then show an error message. Otherwise, go ahead with the conversion

```
supported_currencies = ['USD', ...]
convertFrom = input("What currency would you like to convert from? ")
if convertFrom in supported_currencies:
    convert()
else:
     print("currency not supported")
```

You can also check for convertTo variable whether it exists in the supported list of currencies or not.